# image button "save as" to save file from external servers php script

Tags: php, image, button, download, external

I have a pictrures gallery on my server. The pictures are stored on diffrent external servers. On my server are placed the thumbnails only.
How I can make a button "save as" in php so that a user can download a big picture file which is from external servers. I need a simple php script which can do download a jpg file cross all browser agents and from diffrent external servers. The button will be implemented inside html code. The button is a regular link formated in css style.
So how to do it properly. Thanks.

I would like also that the path of file should be send as a variable parameter to php script somehow.

Comment: Why not just link the user to the original fully-sized image?

Comment: because I don't want that user see the file url address.

Answer (score 1):

I am guessing you are trying to have the pictures be downloaded automatically (you want a dialog box to pop up prompting where to save the file).

There is a great tutorial on this site that uses the `php header function to force download`

Check it out: http://www.ryboe.com/tutorials/php-headers-force-download

Comment: That's right I want a dialog box to pop up prompting where to save the file.

Answer (score 0):

I found some solution with following php script

```
<?PHP
 // Define the path to file
 $file = $_GET['file'];
 $name = basename ($file);
 if(!file)
 {
 // File doesn't exist, output error
 die('file not found');
 }
 else
 {
 // Set headers
 header("Cache-Control: public");
 header("Content-Description: File Transfer");
 header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$name");
 header("Content-Type: image/jpg");
 header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");

 // Read the file from disk
 readfile($file);
 }
 ?>
```

and I can send parameters like url address cross html code

```
<a href="download.php?file=http://someserver/picture.jpg">download</a>
```

The only problem is that it is not working with all servers. It's not woriking for exemple with that file

```
http://backalleypics.com/Pictures/Letter Je~Ju/Jessica Alba/Jessica Alba 230.jpg
```

I don't know what I need to do?

Comment: I noticed that the problem occurs when the url address I send cross html code. When the address is included in the php script like that 
$file = "http://backalleypics.com/Pictures/Letter Je~Ju/Jessica Alba/Jessica Alba 230.jpg"; there is everything ok. But I want just send url cross html code. How I can do that without no problem?

Answer (score 0):

Remove the spaces from your file name:

**change:** `http://backalleypics.com/Pictures/Letter Je~Ju/Jessica Alba/Jessica Alba 230.jpg`

**to:** `http://backalleypics.com/Pictures/Letter_Je~Ju/Jessica_Alba/Jessica_Alba_230.jpg`